# <div>, <p> tags are not considered as block elements in Android browser

Tags: android, html

I have a strange issue with Android browser. the div, p tags aren't considered as blocks in my phone's Android browser. I've used the Eric Myer's reset in the beginning of the style sheet. And here is my HTML code -

```
<body>
<div id="mainwrap">
     <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>  
</body>
```

In that Android browser, p tag is just 50% of the mainwrap. I tried putting p width = 100%, but didn't work. I tried replacing p with a div, still it shows only 50%. Any idea whats the problem? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `display:block;`

Comment: Yes. I tried all that. Didnt work.

Comment: Post all of your HTML and all of your CSS.

Comment: Hi Blender, i removed everything in the page and kept only that much what i've posted here.

Comment: Android reflows text sometimes to fit in the viewport. Chrome for Android also changes the font size of (what it detects as) the main copy of the page in order to be readable. Might it be either of these?

Comment: Not reproducible. Please provide a self-contained document that actually demonstrates the issue. How could you see from the string “Some paragraph” what the element width is? Please specify observable facts about rendering, not assumptions about internals (like “not considered as block elements”).